# How to check if use <10 is not define as tag html?

Tags: php, html, ms-word, export

I want to export html to word using this code

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control:  must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"$namafile.doc\"");
```

but when meet this "<10" is always define as a tag and the value after that always disappear. How can I prevent from that case ?

Expectation 
<10 && >10 print in ms word

reality
<.... nothing print in ms word

Comment: What on earth is `but when meet this "<10"` in this context?

Comment: @HankyPanky means that `<10` is considered as html tag. Though I don't understand how this can happen in Word.

Comment: Are you outputting actual data in .doc format? Or just plaintext which you hope Word will interpret as .doc?

Comment: You need to escape HTML entities

Comment: I use css and html to customize report in word. But when meet string like this "<(number here)" the data printed in document different from expectation.

Comment: You output HTML and you're wondering why something that looks like an HTML tag screws up the formatting‽ If you're going to output HTML instead of an actual DOC file, at least make it valid HTML.

Comment: The problem solved, I use php regex to insert space between that character so it will be like this < 10 and content appear. Now how change this question to answered ??

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved, I use php regex to insert space between that character so it will be like this < 10 and content appear.